# fadeOut fadeIn Chrome issue

Tags: google-chrome, fadein, fadeout

I have tried to fadeOut a div and fadeIn another div in a same time.  It works in Firefox and IE(7-9) correctly, and it works in Chrome too. In chrome, though, after fadeOut, my page has to scroll to the top and then fadeIn.

I want as situation where there isn't a scroll in Google Chrome like in Firefox and IE.

```
$("ul.main_news li:eq(0)").hover(function(){
    $(".a").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300).promise().done(function(){
    $(".b").stop(true, true).fadeIn();  
    }); 
    $(this).removeClass("asew");
    $(this).addClass("sdghe");
    $("ul.main_news li:eq(1)").removeClass("sdghe");
    $("ul.main_news li:eq(1)").addClass("asew");
    });


$("ul.main_news li:eq(1)").hover(function(){
    $(".b").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300).promise().done(function(){
    $(".a").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    });
    $(this).removeClass("asew");
    $(this).addClass("sdghe");
    $("ul.main_news li:eq(0)").removeClass("sdghe");
    $("ul.main_news li:eq(0)").addClass("asew");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want use `stop()` method anywhere! Maybe it has some problem with use in callback of `fadeOut()`!
try this:

```
("ul.main_news li:eq(1)").hover(function(){
      $(".b").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300).promise().done(function(){
        $(".a").fadeIn();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use this code insted of promise()

```
$(".b").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300).queue(function(){
    $(".a").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, glad to see that you've posted your first answer! It is always nice to add a description to the code as well, so OP and others looking for the same answer, fully understand whats going on, and how it differ from what they've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code without a callback:

```
$(".a").stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);       
$(".b").stop(true, true).fadeOut(0);
```